# Lua math.randomseed returns the same value

Tags: lua, openresty

Here is a random generator

```
local hexset = {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8','9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
}

function random_hex(length)
    math.randomseed(os.time())

    if length > 0 then
        return random_hex(length - 1) .. hexset[math.random(1, #hexset)]
    else
        return ""
    end
end

print(utils.random_hex(32))
print(utils.random_hex(32))
print(utils.random_hex(32))
print(utils.random_hex(32))
```

The 4 `print` give me the exact same RequestSid:

```
46421938586706fff767d26410f524ee
46421938586706fff767d26410f524ee
46421938586706fff767d26410f524ee
46421938586706fff767d26410f524ee
```

I'm using this in my openresty app. I tried to set `math.randomseed(os.time())` once in my lua top level too. Then after making 100 concurrent calls, I get about 6 duplicate hex.

Comment: no need to store characters in tables, you can just do `local hex = "01234`...`cdef"` and then use `string.sub(hex, n, n)` where n is the index of the character you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.randomseed` first takes it's argument and converts it to an integer. The integral part of `os.time()` typically only changes once every second, so you will get the same sequence of random values for one second with this approach.

You probably don't want to repeatedly set the random seed. Setting it once at the beginning of the program should be enough (though `math.random` is likely not a very high quality random number generator).

Comment: The example in the question uses `os.time()` though.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the question. I removed the last paragraph since it would be confusing here

Answer (score 1):

Take the `math.randomseed(os.time())` out of your function and it should work fine.

```
local hexset = {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8','9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
}

math.randomseed(os.time())

function random_hex(length)
    if length > 0 then
        return random_hex(length - 1) .. hexset[math.random(1, #hexset)]
    else
        return ""
    end
end

print(random_hex(32))
print(random_hex(32))
print(random_hex(32))
print(random_hex(32))
```